# In a URI, https://www.google.com/items/2 how to get 2 alone (item id) to process further

Tags: servlets, path-parameter

In a URI, https://www.google.com/items/2   how to get 2 alone (item id) to process further

Comment: is this URI a part of the request?

Answer (score -1):

**PATH VARIABLE**

Its called PATH VARIABLE, this is just different type of HTTP REQUEST to send parameters within API.
In SpringBoot we can use PATH VARIABLE like this :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("car")
public class CarController {

    @Autowired
    CarService carservice;

    @GetMapping("{id}")
    public Car getCarById(@PathVariable long id) {

    return carService.findById(id)
  }
}
```

Then you can call your api like this and send car id in last url

> localhost:8080/car/1

Comment: OP did nowhere said he's using Spring MVC. Just basic Servlets as indicated by the question tags. And Spring MVC (REST) controllers are absolutely not Servlets.